# Git List Commits By Blobs

Tags: git

Say I have the SHA for a blob. I can go git show  and see the contents of the blob. Is it possible to get a list of all the commits that contain that blob?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following scriptlet should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh

blob=deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef

git rev-list --all |
while read commit; do
    if git ls-tree -r $commit | grep -q $blob; then
        echo $commit
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but `git show <abbrev-sha1>` will show the contents of that blob etc. As will `git cat-file blob <abbrev-sha1>`, use `git cat-file -t <abbrev-sha1>` to check it's a blob.

Getting the first (or last) commit that contained it appears not as easy (such as determining from a patch's diff `index` line, where that patch came from)